# load external property file values in logback.xml

Tags: spring-boot, logback

My property file is in "`E:\config\temp\application-serivce.properties`" and in that file i'm have mentioned log file path as "`logging.path=F:\support\conf\logs`".

In `logback-spring.xml` i have mentioned like below

```
<appender name="FILE-ERROR"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/log.${timestamp}.log</file>
</appender>
```

But still i'm not able to create log in desired path which mentioned in property file, is any other way to load the value of the property file in logback.xml.here i'm  using spring boot

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of google i have found the solution.I have included like below in logback.xml
and log file path i've mentioned like `logger_path=F:\support\conf\logs`

```
<property file="E:\config\temp\application-serivce.properties" />
```

and

```
<property name="LOG_PATH" value="${logger_path}" />
<appender name="FILE-ERROR"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/log.${timestamp}.log</file>
</appender>
```

cheers!

Comment: Thanks it's working useful when you have external properties file and you want to keep logging seperately

Answer (score 1):

You may also reference it as resource on the class path (add it resources folder) if you don't want to use absolute path.

```
<property resource="application-serivce.properties" />
```